# OpenCV: Identifying parts of image

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am trying to identify the major parts of the image below. I am looking to find the 6 parts as highlighted.
I tried to use combinations of blurring/dilate/erode and applied the findCountures() but not able to get these major parts as single unit.

Can anyone suggest the best approach to do this. I am including the code that can produce the image as well.

```
import cv2
import numpy as  np

def createImage():
    points = [
        [(0, 8), (5, 8)],        [(5, 8), (10, 12)],        [(10, 12), (15, 26)],
        [(15, 26), (20, 56)],        [(20, 56), (25, 82)],        [(25, 82), (30, 102)],
        [(30, 102), (35, 129)],        [(35, 129), (40, 100)],        [(40, 100), (45, 81)],
        [(45, 81), (50, 80)],        [(50, 80), (55, 81)],        [(55, 81), (60, 84)],
        [(60, 84), (65, 104)],        [(65, 104), (70, 151)],        [(70, 151), (75, 151)],
        [(75, 151), (80, 159)],        [(80, 159), (85, 191)],        [(85, 191), (90, 193)],
        [(90, 193), (95, 230)],        [(95, 230), (100, 230)],        [(100, 230), (105, 248)],
        [(105, 248), (110, 224)],        [(110, 224), (115, 199)],        [(115, 199), (120, 170)],
        [(120, 170), (125, 130)],        [(125, 130), (130, 101)],        [(130, 101), (135, 69)],
        [(135, 69), (140, 61)],        [(140, 61), (145, 59)],        [(145, 59), (150, 62)],
        [(150, 62), (155, 85)],        [(155, 85), (160, 104)],        [(160, 104), (165, 117)],
        [(165, 117), (170, 89)],[(170, 89), (175, 71)],[(175, 71), (180, 43)],[(180, 43), (185, 21)]
    ]
    img = np.zeros([256,256],dtype=np.uint8)

    for p in points:
        cv2.line(img,p[0],p[1],255,1)

    cv2.imwrite("sample.png",img)
    return img

img  =createImage()
cv2.imshow("sample",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: picture_with_highligts]

[image: original_picture]

Comment: See the link picture_with_highligts to see the expected major parts

Comment: [Hough lines](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d10/tutorial_py_houghlines.html) is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is using `FastLineDetector`.

If you apply `FastLineDetector` to your input image, the result will be:

[image]

Let's see how we got the result:

- 1. Implement the `FastLineDetector`

---

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("KZd2a.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
d = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector()
lines = d.detect(gray)
```

- 2. Draw the lines

---

```
r = d.drawSegments(i, lines)
```

But if we analyze, there are 20 lines drawn to the image.

```py
for line in lines:
    (x1, y1, x2, y2) = [i for i in line[0]]
    cv2.line(i, pt1=(x1, y1), pt2=(x2, y2), color=(255, 255, 0), thickness=4)
```

Steps:

---

- [image]